# VB.NET not having form text show up as application

Tags: vb.net

When a new form (winforms) is created and shown, the caption on every active form shows up as a separate application in Task Manager.  Is there a way to give my application a name independent of caption on forms?  And if I have more than one form active at a time, to not have both show up in Task Manager?

I am sure this has been asked hundreds of times, but I can't seem to Google up an answer.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of a very simple demonstration.  In task manager, it is showing both form1 and form2.

[image]

Comment: This is certainly not normal and has not been asked hundreds of times.  The Windows version as well as a screenshot and a small repro snippet is required to document the problem better.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit.  The startup form does have active X controls, so I don't know if that is a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an MDIPARENT to house your forms when running.  If you do not want an MDI, you will have to manually maintain which forms are visible and what thier captions are.

[MDI Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx)

Comment: Works as expected and became cleaner using an MDI.